# My OSX's download speed is limited

Tags: macos, networking

With the same wireless network environment(2Mbps), the speed of downloading in Windows(another computer) is around 200Kbytes. while in OSX(have an Macbook Pro / 10.6.8), it's limited around 100Kbytes(same url). Is there any way I could check where the problem is?

I have full access to the wireless router and it doesn't have any configurations on this.

Comment: What are you downloading? Where from? Have you done repeated tests to multiple hosts and averaged the download speed to rule out (expected) variance? Are both machines connected wirelessly? Does the speed improve for both machines if you connect through an Ethernet cable?

Comment: As slhck suggests, try using this http://www.speakeasy.net/speedtest/ as a more accurate method of testing each OS.

Comment: @slhck What are you downloading? A speed testing file provided by ISP. Have you done repeated tests to multiple hosts and averaged the download speed to rule out (expected) variance? Sure.  Are both machines connected wirelessly?  Yes. Does the speed improve for both machines if you connect through an Ethernet cable? My MBP's ethernet  network is broken, so i cannot test this.